# How can I deploy a trained CNN model to production on a ARM?

Tags: python, keras, arm, conv-neural-network, microprocessors

I have trained a CNN model with Keras for semantic segmentation of craneal images and saved the weights and this trained model.

Now, I want to put it into production on a microprocessor. The pipeline of the process in the micro involves reading an image from a sensor and using it as input for the CNN model (U-Net). Then, the resulted binary image is used as a mask for an area of interest from which a variable is measured. Finally, a number is given as a result.

So, is it possible to load a trained model on a microprocessor? And if so, how?

Which features should have the microprocessor in order to work with CNN models?

Thanks in advance!